# How to draw chart using WPF and IronPython

Tags: wpf, charts, ironpython

I'm a french beginner dev and I need to draw charts using WPF and IronPython. I'm coding with MVS2010 and I didn't find any help on Google.
Does anybody have an idea ? Something to help me ?

Thanks all,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Charting is difficult, and it's usually best to rely on a tried-and-true library like [ChartFX](http://www.softwarefx.com/sfxNetProducts/ChartFX/wpf/) and invest your time and energy into solving real business problems.

If you have difficulty convincing your management to purchase the library, divide the cost by your weekly pay and think about if it's possible to build something better in that many weeks. More than likely it's not.

If you're just learning, there are also some open source options like [VISIFire](http://www.visifire.com/).