# Charting with IronPython

Tags: charts, ironpython

I'm trying to plot a signal in IronPython (VS 2012 Environment), from my quick [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=charting%20tool%20for%20iron%20python) I couldn't find anything useful, other than couple of paid options

[ChartFX](http://www.softwarefx.com/sfxNetProducts/ChartFX/wpf/) &  [VISIFire](http://www.visifire.com/)

found from a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185092/how-to-draw-chart-using-wpf-and-ironpython) (4 years ago),

Just wondering if there's any open source charting tool available now for Iron Python, `please note` Trail or Community edition aren't an option.

any suggestions would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a specific UI technology in mind? Do you need to do something interactive or just generate/print/...? Have you seen http://oxyplot.org/ and https://code.google.com/p/ironlab/ as these are common options that often come up ...

Comment: wpf would do, I'm looking something similar to ZedGraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OxyPlot](http://oxyplot.org/) is a modern cross-platform plotting library for .NET.

It is published under the MIT license and can therefore be used in commercial projects.

It supports lots of chart types, provides examples and documentation and is under active development.